# What products which support 110V/60Hz you can use in Europe with a power converter to 110V/50Hz

Tags: converter

I was wondering what products which only support 110V/60Hz you can use in Europe with a power converter from 230V/50Hz to 110V/50Hz.
In what product the different frequency will be a problem ? and in what products the different frequency will not be a problem?

P.S
I am thinking about this product:
https://www.oxo.com/oxo-on-9-cup-coffee-maker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to know the internals of the design to be able to draw a conclusion, else you're just guessing. But here are the general issues with running a 60 Hz device on 50 Hz (at same voltage after conversion).

Heating elements -- effectively no effect on heating element. Hair dryers, simple coffee makers, immersion heaters, etc. But the motor and controller parts will be affected. More below.

Stuff with magnetic coils will run hot because of X = 2*pi*f*L. You have same inductance (L) but now you've reduce the frequency (f) so impedance X is lower. So now current draw increases 20% because the impedance is lower.

"Universal" motors -- increased heating and higher speed due to higher current. Universal motors are the kind with brushes used in electric drills, variable speed kitchen mixers, etc.

Transformers -- increased heating due to lower impedance. These are used in old-school wall adapters, clock radios, etc.

Synchronous motors -- increased heating, slower running, possible damage. Runs slower from lower line frequency. Often used in AC powered mechanical clocks, mechanical timers in appliances.

Induction motors -- increased heating, slower running, possible damage. These are fixed speed motors often used in electric fans and bench equipment like bench grinders, drill press.

Electronics will also have issues at lower frequencies:

Switching power supplies -- lower output current. Stuff like phone chargers, laptop charger, etc. These typically convert the line AC to line DC with a bridge rectifier filtered to DC by a large capacitor then high voltage DC is converted to low voltage. Output current capability will be lower since it has longer time between input capacitor recharge due to lower line frequency.

Microcontrollers -- slower timing if using line frequency as reference. Microcontrollers are the brains behind smarter coffee makers, microwave ovens, etc. Most use accurate quartz crystals or a resonator for timing, but on AC powered devices, it is cheaper to use the AC line frequency for timing. If your smart device has a fixed AC cord (not a wall adapter), then it could have a problem with slower timing. For example, 1 minute on a microwave oven might actually be 1 minute 12 seconds.

Hope that helps, -Vince

Comment: So you do not think there will be a problem with the coffee machine?

Comment: There's a fair chance the clock will run slow. If the electronics is powered by a small transformer (I'd say 50/50 chance), then that transformer would run hotter.

If you want to check before going overseas, you can borrow or rent a generator (as in the gas powered kind) and adjust the speed to get 50 Hz and see how it affects the coffee maker. The simpler generators (not the fancy inverter type) have a speed adjustment and a 50 Hz/60 Hz indicator.

Comment: A coffee machine will be fairly high power - couldn't find a rating for yours, but I'd expect 1000 watts or so.  You must choose a 220V->120V converter that is capable of handling the power required by the coffee maker - at that power, it probably won't be cheap or small/light.  I think it is generally best to buy appliances that are designed to be used where you intend to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Slim to none. Some rice cookers and similar with mechanical synchronous timers will run too slow. Running a 60 Hz motor on 50 Hz will heat it slightly less and you will be hard pressed to find one which does not have 20 % extra cooling from the start. Any NTSC video equipment that syncs to your grid won't work well but you won't damage it either.

Comment: So what so you think about the coffee maker that I posted in the original post?

Comment: @Oren Zero issues.